# pandas - Compute a function of each group in different columns

Tags: python, pandas

I  have a standard grouping of a large DataFrame:

```
agroup = data.groupby("Product No")
```

I then would like to apply a function to each of these groups. This function computes two values for each group

```
def compute_thing(df):
   v1, v2 = calc(df)
   return v1, v2
```

What I need is a DataFrame with two columns, each coming from the tuple.

I tried doing:

```
agroup.apply(compute_thing)
```

But this creates a single column, and puts the values in a tuple. I tried returning series or dicts from `compute_thing`, but it never worked..

Any ideas how to approach this?

Comment: try to add some snapshot of `df`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`compute_thing` should return a DataFrame, rather than a tuple. For example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'foo': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
        'bar': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    })

def compute_thing(group):
    return pd.DataFrame({
            'foo_mu': group['foo'].mean(),
            'bar_mu': group['bar'].mean()
        }, index=[0])

df.groupby('foo').apply(compute_thing)
```

which results in

```
       bar_mu  foo_mu
foo                  
1   0     1.5       1
2   0     3.5       2
3   0     5.5       3
```

Comment: I am having some issues understanding the type of your `group` argument to `compute_thing()`. Shouldn't apply iterate over the results of the grouping, and the `group` argument refers to the current group in consideration?

Comment: Yep, and that's what happens: `group` is a DataFrame containing the data contained within the current group.

Comment: By the way, I came back to this response, and realized that there is a MultiIndex with an annoying `0`. I guess we can get rid of this through some kind of `stack`/`unstack` operation, but isn't there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: @user1496984 You can write `res.index = res.index.droplevel(1)`, where `res = df.groupby('foo').apply(compute_thing)`.